# Is there a way to create a function that uses multiple argument, and run the same function independently for each one of them?

Tags: r, function, arguments, multiple-arguments

I'm pretty new in programming, but I'm trying to learn through practice. I'm coding a function which accepts a variable number of arguments, with the `...` function. Here's an example of what I've done:

> decyph_test = function(...) {
> decript = letters[...]
> return(decript)
> }

If I enter only one argument (in this case, the required argument is a number, 'cause its used to locate that position in the `letter` constant) there's no big problem. But, what I want to do is to enter multiple numbers, so each one of them is located to its respective letter, and then is compiled into a vector, which would be the `return` of the function. Is there any specific way in which I can make any individual argument run the same process of locating its letter counterpart?

Comment: `I'm coding a function` What _language_ are you using?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to say that. I'm using R,